# Changing the tint color for only the selected segment in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am re-doing one of my projects in swift from objective-c and i have one function i use in objective-C that i can't get translated properly.

This is the Objective-C code

```
- (void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segment");

    for (int e=0; e<[sender.subviews count]; e++) {
        if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:e]isSelected]) {

            [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:e] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"]]];
        } else {
            [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:e] setTintColor:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where i am in swift

```
func segChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    println("Value Changed")
    var e:Int = 0
    var countOfSeg = sender.subviews.count
    for (e=0; e < countOfSeg; e++) {

    }

    print(sender.subviews[e]) 
}
```

It won't let me put **.selected** on the end of **sender.subviews[e]** for the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

`subviews` is an array of AnyObjects, so you'll need to cast each item to UIControl before you can reference its `selected` property:

```
for item in control.subviews {
    if let subview = item as? UIControl {
        if subview.selected {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: This compiles, but doesn't work at runtime. In iOS 8, it looks like the control's subviews are instances of a private UISegment class, which is actually a subclass of UIImageView. The attempt to cast each item to UIControl will fail silently. I haven't done what you're trying, so not sure why this was working in iOS 7. Either Apple has changed how UISegmentedControl is built, or UIImageView has a private `selected` property. I'd recommend you implement this effect some other way, which might mean building a custom version of the segmented control. If you really want to keep using the internal subviews, change "UIControl" to "UIImageView" and change "if subview.selected..." to "if subview.highlighted...". Just keep in mind that this might not work on iOS 7, and could break again in a later version of iOS.

Comment: subview.selected wasn't an option for me

Comment: My fault - selected is a property on UIControl, not UIView. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble, where do i place this?

Comment: it won't go past the if let subview line either

Comment: My response wouldn't fit as a comment so I've added it below the answer.

Comment: +1 for the detailed edit, but it doesn't get the check because it did not answer my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try below  code

```
let sortedViews = segmentedControl.subviews.sort( { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )
        for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerate() {
            if index == segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
                view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 17/255, green: 125/255, blue: 185/255, alpha: 1)
            } else {
                view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Try this one :)

```
    self.segmentcontrol.selectionStyle = .box;
    self.segmentcontrol.selectionIndicatorBoxColor = UIColor.blue
```

To make Selection indicator color as same as the box color do this.

```
    self.segmentcontrol.selectionIndicatorColor = UIColor.blue
```

Answer (score 0):

updated version for swift 5
        let sortedViews = sender.subviews.sorted( by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )

```
    for (index, view) in sortedViews.enumerated() {
        if index == sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.blue //UIColor.blueColor()
        } else {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
```